# Embed Windows Media Player in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi how do I go about embeding Windows Media Player in PHP ? what I want is when the user clicks the link a new window pops up to play the video in it's original size & when the user checks the page source he wont find the direct link to the video file, without using activex if possible.

Comment: You can't hide the link to the video with WMP. Flash might be able to do this (well, at least make it tougher). But as long as you put something online, it's never gonna be completely private.

Comment: if it plays on my screen i have it, and can then do 'whatever' with it.

Comment: How would you like to tell the media player what media to play without actually telling it what to play?  I don't think we've quite hit the point where human-to-computer telepathy works...

Answer (score 0):

PHP has nothing to do with Windows Media Player. At most it can generate the appropriate HTML to invoke a media player on the client's machine (via `<object>` and/or `<embed>` and/or `<video>`, but there's no guarantee it would be media player. You cannot force a particular player. What if they're on a Mac? Or a Unix machine? No WMP there...

At best you can obscure the address, but when push comes to shove, the address of the media file HAS to be sent to the client so their player can retrieve the data for playing.